# my laravel 4 form to upload a product is not sending ifo to the database

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-form

The input form is not sending the input to the database, i even changed the Post to Put it staring sending info to the URL but thats it still did not end up in the database. By the way im using SQLite,
Could really use some help or input.

```
     <section class="wrapper">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <!-- Standar Form -->
      <form method="POST" action="{{ action('UploadController@handleCreate') }}" role="form">
        <fieldset>
          <h5>Upload Your Product's Files Here</h5>
          <div class="form-actions form-group">
            <input type="file"  name="filepath" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">
              Product Name
            </label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name of your Product" type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="developer_name">
              Developer Name
            </label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="developer name" type="text" name="developer_name" id="developer_name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">
              The Description Of Your Product
            </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"  type="text" name="description"/>
          </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="OS">
            Compatible Operating System
          </label>
          <select class="form-control" name="OS"/>
          <option value="Crossplatform">Cross Platform</option>
          <option value="OSX">OSX</option>
          <option value="Windows">Windows</option>
          <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
          <option value="IOS">IOS</option>
          <option value="Android">Android</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">
          Set The Price (if free leave as is)
        </label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" type="decimal" name="price" id="price"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">
          Choose a category for your product
        </label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category"/>
        <option value="free">Free</option>
        <option value="premuim">Premium</option>
        <option value="opensource">Opensource</option>
        <option value="collaborativeefforts">Collabritive Efforts</option>
        <option value="developertools">Developer Tools</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <h4>upload a thumbnail for your product</h4>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <input type="file"  name="image" />
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-actions form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
      <a href="{{ action('UploadController@getindex') }}" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

And here is the part of the controller that handles the form submission controller

```
public function create()
          {
            return View::make('developerpanel.upload.index');
          }

          //Handle create form submission.
          public function handleCreate()
          {
            $product = new Product;
            $product->filepath       = Input::file('filepath');
            $product->name           = Input::get('name');
            $product->developer_name = Input::get('developer_name');
            $product->description    = Input::get('description');
            $product->OS             = Input::get('OS');
            $product->price          = Input::get('price');
            $product->category       = Input::get('category');
            $product->image          = Input::file('image');
            $product->save();


            return Redirect::route('developerpanel.index');
             }
```

Could really use the help Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're uploading files, your form needs to have an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('UploadController@handleCreate') }}" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, you don't want to just try to save the file object to the database like that. Check out the Laravel docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files) regarding file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel's methods, and maybe do some validation to make sure it's an image file.

[validation#rule-image](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-image)

[html#opening-a-form](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

```
{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'UploadController@handleCreate', 'role'=>'form', 'files'=>true)) }}

   ...

{{ Form::close() }}
```